# What does 'show_caches' and 'adaptive' arguments do in `dis.dis` function

Tags: python, python-3.11

Python `3.11` introduces new two parameters to the `dis.dis` function, `show_caches` and `adaptive`.

```
>>> import dis
>>>
>>> help(dis.dis)
Help on function dis in module dis:

dis(x=None, *, file=None, depth=None, show_caches=False, adaptive=False)
    Disassemble classes, methods, functions, and other compiled objects.

    With no argument, disassemble the last traceback.

    Compiled objects currently include generator objects, async generator
    objects, and coroutine objects, all of which store their code object
    in a special attribute.
```

What does this parameters means in python 3.11?. I did check the result by setting it to `True` but the result remains same as like setting it to `False`.

```
>>> dis.dis("a = 1", show_caches=True, adaptive=True)
  0           0 RESUME                   0

  1           2 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              4 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
>>>
>>> dis.dis("a = 1")
  0           0 RESUME                   0

  1           2 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              4 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: The `show_caches` parameter is explained somewhat higher up in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/dis.html): _Changed in version 3.11: Some instructions are accompanied by one or more inline cache entries, which take the form of CACHE instructions. These instructions are hidden by default, but can be shown by passing `show_caches=True` to any dis utility._

Comment: @kaya3 It is in the docs, just not where one might expect them. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `show_caches` argument is described at the very top of [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/dis.html) documentation since it is possible to pass it to many of the module's functions:

> Changed in version 3.11: Some instructions are accompanied by one or more inline cache entries, which take the form of [`CACHE`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/dis.html#opcode-CACHE)  instructions. These instructions are hidden by default, but can be shown by passing `show_caches=True` to any dis utility.

`adaptive` is described under [`CACHE`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/dis.html#opcode-CACHE) documentation:

> Rather than being an actual instruction, this opcode is used to mark extra space for the interpreter to cache useful data directly in the bytecode itself. It is automatically hidden by all dis utilities, but can be viewed with `show_caches=True`.
>
> Logically, this space is part of the preceding instruction. Many opcodes expect to be followed by an exact number of caches, and will instruct the interpreter to skip over them at runtime.
>
> Populated caches can look like arbitrary instructions, so great care should be taken when reading or modifying raw, adaptive bytecode containing quickened data.
>
> New in version 3.11.

Comment: It would be helpful to have an example of an instruction accompanied by a CACHE instruction, to demonstrate this; it's not clear if `dis` would always show a `CACHE` instruction, or if it might show the contents of such a cache. The second part does contain the word "adaptive", but not in reference to the argument of that name, so it's not clear what that argument is supposed to do.

Comment: @DeepSpace Thank you for your answer. But I really appreciate if could include an example to demonstrate the usage of those two parameters.